# How to execute a java main class from the command line

Tags: java, command-line, compilation

My class:

```
package com.your.company.cli;

import com.github.domain.cli.Cli;
import com.your.company.utils.MySuperClass;

public class Hello {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws TechnicalException {
        new Cli().runcli(MySuperClass.class, args);
    }
}
```

On my Eclipse is OK:

[image]

I need run my class by a command line. (after compile by Maven (mvn clean install))

```
java -cp .... ???? com.your.company.cli.Hello ... ???
```

**EDIT 1:**

I try `java -jar myproject.jar`

aucun attribut manifest principal dans myproject.jar

I try `java -cp myproject.jar com.your.company.cli.Hello`

impossible de trouver la classe principale com.your.company.cli.Hello

**EDIT 2:**

I try add `maven-jar-plugin` but my result is a Maven jar (not a fat jar). I looking for a solution with commande line without jar file please (**juste the same behavior as on Eclipse**).

Comment: did you tried to run the whole jar ? with `java -jar `?

Comment: is it possible without jar file?

Comment: `mvn clean install` didn't create a jar file under `target` folder ?

Comment: 'java -jar myproject.jar' do not work. aucun attribut manifest principal dans myproject.jar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I find solution without modify my project:

```
mvn clean install
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=com.your.company.cli.Hello
```

Answer (score 0):

- You can launch the jar file created with `java -jar /target/myproject.jar`.
- You cannot use `java -cp ...` or `javac` because you need to put all java files in the same folder to be compiled.
- For the error `aucun attribut manifest principal dans myproject.jar` is generated because java could not find main class i advise you to add this to your pom.xml file

`

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.2</version>
      <configuration>
        <archive>
          <manifest>
            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
            <mainClass>com.mypackage.MyClass</mainClass>
          </manifest>
        </archive>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

and mention full name of your main class

[UPDATE]

- In case you have multiple dependecies and you want to include all of them with your final jar you can use `maven-assembly-plugin` like this :

  `<plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <phase>package</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>single</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <archive>
              <manifest>
                <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
              </manifest>
            </archive>
            <descriptorRefs>
              <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
            </descriptorRefs>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>`

you must **replace** `${mainClass}` with your main class full name

Comment: if I have more one main class?

Comment: how is this possible sir ? you must have only one main class, the entry point to your project/program

Comment: Yes, i can have more one entries point (main actions, CLI action, admin action, ...)

Comment: I add `maven-jar-plugin` but my jar do not contain any dependencies in `lib/`. So I have this error: `Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/github/foo/exception/TechnicalException`